# Find N-th element in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found this [programming challenge](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/82/A). I was wondering if it's possible to find a mathematical formula of the sequence, which, If I understood, is the following: `A B C D E AA BB CC DD EE AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE AAAAAAAA ...` and I am to find the $N$-term.

I like the challenge but so far I couldn't work out a solution. I have searched a number of websites to look for similar problems, but have only found explanations on standard arithmetic, geometric, quadratic and cubic sequences. Would someone point me out good sources I could start with? Thanks

Comment: I assume this is from a *finished* challenge, is that right?

Comment: Well, given $N$, first figure out how long the consecutive block containing the $N^{th}$ term is.  That's straightforward, noting that there are exactly $5$ blocks of any given length.  Once you know the length, it should be an easy matter to sort out which specific block it is in.

Comment: @AnilCh Perhaps, but I haven't really searched for a solution on this website. I'd like to work it out by myself but I can't figure out where to start :)

Comment: From the link, it appears that this was a problem on a $2011$ challenge.

Comment: If we are looking for the $9^{th}$ term is it DD or B(the second letter of BB)?  The first is much easier.

Comment: I added spaces only for ease of reading the sequence. the $9^{th}$ element should be 'B'.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your original programming challenge in python:

```
from math import log, ceil

names = ['Sheldon', 'Leonard', 'Penny', 'Rajesh', 'Howard']

def consumedDrinks(cycle):
    return len(names) * ((2 ** cycle) - 1)

def findCycle(drink):
    return ceil(log(drink / len(names) + 1, 2))

def lastCycleDrinks(drink):
    return drink - consumedDrinks(findCycle(drink) - 1)

def findLastDrinkPerson(drink):
    cycle = findCycle(drink)
    samePersons = 2 ** (cycle - 1)
    remainingDrinks = lastCycleDrinks(drink)
    index = (remainingDrinks - 1) // samePersons
    return names[index]

print(findLastDrinkPerson(1))
print(findLastDrinkPerson(6))
print(findLastDrinkPerson(1802))
print(findLastDrinkPerson(892656984))
print(findLastDrinkPerson(692293845123452346656984))
```

The program prints:

```
Sheldon
Sheldon
Penny
Leonard
Howard
```

Some explanations:

- **Cycle**: You have 5 persons initially, they will take their drinks in the first cycle. After that you have 10 persons and they will take their drinks in the second cycle. After that you have 20 persons and they will take their drinks in the third cycle etc.
- Function **consumedDrinks(cycle)**: Returns the total number of consumed drinks when the given cycle ends (sum of geometric progression).
- Function **findCycle(n)**: Returns the cycle to which the *n*-th drink belongs.
- Function **lastCycleDrinks(n)**: Returns the number of drinks that will be consumed in the last cycle for a given number of drinks *n*.
- Function **findLastDrinkPerson(n)**: Finds the name of the person that will drink the *n*-th drink (solution to the problem).

The idea is to find the number of cycles needed to drink the last drink. After that you can calculate how many drinks will remain in the last cycle. You can also calculate the number of same persons in the line in the last cycle (it doubles with every cycle). With all that it's easy to find the name of the person who drinks the last drink.

Comment: Thanks for the formula.

Comment: @Celdor You can be tempted to replace $\text{2**n}$ in the given code with $\text{2 << n}$ to save a few CPU cycles but in Python it seems that the first (exponent) version is slightly faster, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053379/times-two-faster-than-bit-shift-for-python-3-x-integers

Comment: Thanks. I've noticed the same occurs in Java 11 and 14 when I was testing an iterative version of this algorithm. On calculating a `7230702951th` drink, I've got these timings  2.3 ms and  0.47 ms when using the bit shifting and multiplication on integers, respectively.